# Benchmark problems for Benders Decomposition

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming, stochastic-programming, benders-decomposition, benchmark

We are implementing a scheduling model using Benders Decomposition. Does someone know of any existing implementation of Benders or any repositories that contain continuous or integer problems solved using Benders Decomposition?

Comment: Are you looking specifically for Benders approaches to scheduling problems, or just any Benders implementations. Do you have a specific solver in mind?

Comment: Thanks for responding! We are looking for code and data sets for multi-stage recourse problems. However, any other Benders implementation would also be fine.

Comment: If you're using CPLEX, it ships with source code for Benders examples.

Answer (score 1):

Some collections of testing instances for **Stochastic Programming** which can be solved by the **Benders Decomposition / L-shaped / SDDP**:

- MSPLib-Library https://github.com/bonnkleiford/MSPLib-Library
- SIPLIB: A Stochastic Integer Programming Test Problem Library [https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~sahmed/siplib/](https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/%7Esahmed/siplib/)
- A (PO)rtable (S)tochastic programming (T)est (S)et (POSTS) [https://users.iems.northwestern.edu/~jrbirge/html/dholmes/post.html](https://users.iems.northwestern.edu/%7Ejrbirge/html/dholmes/post.html)
- Test-Problem Collection for Stochastic Linear Programming https://www4.uwsp.edu/math/afelt/slptestset.html

Comment: Thanks a lot @Penghui Guo! The test problems in these repositories will help us a lot in verifying the correctness of our implementation.